# Can't open camera page anymore after implementing camera plugin

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4, capacitor

I want to use the native camera with capacitor camera plugin. But after implementing, I can't open the page anymore (when I click the button that routes me to that page nothing happens) I found out that error has to be in the commented html section. But it doesnt show an error. The whole app loads when the section is not commented.

page.html

```
<ion-content>
  <!--
    <ion-card>
  <img
    role="button"
    class="image"
    (click)="onPickImage"
    [src]="selectedImage"
    *ngIf="selectedImage"
  >
  </ion-img>
</ion-card>
-->

<ion-footer>
  <ion-button (click)="onPickImage()" *ngIf="!selectedImage" class="buttonPost" expand="full" color="primary">Take Photo</ion-button>


</ion-footer>
```

page.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Output, EventEmitter  } from '@angular/core';
import { Plugins, Capacitor, CameraSource, CameraResultType } from '@capacitor/core';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-cam',
  templateUrl: './cam.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./cam.page.scss'],
})

//Native Kamerafunk. importieren hier
export class CamPage implements OnInit {
  @Output() imagePick = new EventEmitter<String>();
  selectedImage: string;

  constructor() { }


  onPickImage() {
    if (!Capacitor.isPluginAvailable('Camera')) {
      return; //falls kein Kamera vorhanden ist. 
    }
    Plugins.Camera.getPhoto({
      quality: 50,
      source: CameraSource.Prompt, //Prompt heisst entweder Gallery oder Camera vlt stylischer seperater Button hinzufügen
      correctOrientation: true,
      height: 320,
      width: 200,
      resultType: CameraResultType.Base64 //Img encoded into a string, can be converted into a file
    }).then(image => {    
      this.selectedImage = image.base64String;
      this.imagePick.emit(image.base64String);
    }).catch(error => {      //Error Handler
      console.log(error);
      return false;
    })

  }


  onImagePicked(image: string) {

  }



  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to note is that you shouldn't actually use the `Base64` encoding options.

It's a known bad piece of documentation as it leads people to using it, when it's not a best practice.

The reason is that it uses a lot of memory this way and crashes some devices.

Secondly, when you say there is no error, do you mean no error displayed visually?

When Ionic/Angular crashes it will dump the message out to the console.

You can see this by using the browser developer tools:

[Using Chrome DevTools - Android Development - Ionic Documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/building/android#using-chrome-devtools)

or if you are on Mac:

[Using Safari Web Inspector - iOS Development - Ionic Documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/building/ios#using-safari-web-inspector)

Comment: I actually get this error `ERROR
Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors: 'app-image-picker' is not a known element` despite me adding it to the exports of the shared module

Comment: This is a different question so I would recommend either starting a new one or editing this one to attract people that can help - they aren't going to find your problem tucked away in a comment. Upvote what has already helped. If you have added it to a shared module then have you imported that shared module in. Seems like a specific and easily solvable issue. Perhaps taking a look at Josh's tutorial which explains [how to set up a shared module](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=za5NaFavux4) and use it in pages will get you unstuck.